# How to use refinements dynamically

Tags: ruby

Trying to make sense of this 'refinements' business.

I'm making a module which refines a core class:

```
module StringPatch
  refine String do
    def foo
      true
    end
  end
end
```

Then a class to use the refinement

```
class PatchedClass
end

PatchedClass.send :using, StringPatch
```

I get this error:

```
RuntimeError: Module#using is not permitted in methods
```

How can I make this work?
I am trying to dynamically patch core classes in a certain scope only. I want to make the patches available in the class and instance scope.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, the refinement is active until the end of the script when `using` is in main, and until the end of the current Class/Module definition when `using` is in a Class or Module.

```
module StringPatch
  refine String do
    def foo
      true
    end
  end
end

class PatchedClass
  using StringPatch
  puts "test".foo
end

class PatchedClass
  puts "test".foo #=> undefined method `foo' for "test":String (NoMethodError)
end
```

This would mean that if you manage to dynamically call `using` on a Class or Module, its effect will be directly removed.

You cannot use `refine` in methods, but you can define methods in a Class that has been refined :

```
class PatchedClass
  using StringPatch
  def foo
    "test".foo #=> true
  end
end

class PatchedClass
  def bar
    "test".foo
  end
end

patched = PatchedClass.new
puts patched.foo  #=> true
puts patched.bar  #=> undefined method `foo' for "test":String (NoMethodError)
```

For your questions, this [discussion](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11779) could be interesting. It looks like refinements are restricted on purpose, but I don't know why :

> Because refinement activation should be as static as possible.

Comment: How can you use the refinement in instance methods?

Comment: And do you know of another way to achieve dynamic, scoped patches?

Comment: I appreciate your help. I saw that thread, but couldn't really make sense of it, which is why I posted here! I have 6 'patch classes' and I want to apply them all at once. It looks like refinements are going to be difficult to use. I will have to poke around for something else.

Comment: You could ask another question with a better description of your classes and how you'd like to use them.

Answer (score 3):

Refinements are strictly scoped and can't be used dynamically as it stands. I get around this by structuring modules such that I can use them a refinement or as a monkey patch when needed. There are still limitations to this approach, and with refinements in general, but still handy.

```
module StringPatch      
    def foo
      true
    end

    refine String do
      include StringPatch
    end
 end
```

Used as a refinement

```
class PatchedClass
   using StringPatch
end
```

Used as a single instance patch

```
obj = PatchedClass.new
obj.extend(StringPatch)
```

You can of course also extend the whole class as a monkey patch but then you pollute the class forever and for all eternity.

```
PatchedClass.prepend(StringPatch)
```

Comment: I tried running the first three code snippets then `obj.instance_exec { "".foo }` but got NoMethodError. I'm close to giving up on dynamic, scoped patching of core classes.

Comment: If you're going to use it per instance then you can just `obj.extend(YourModuleWithMethods)` and `obj.foo` Depending on what you're doing though it might not be performant to do it that way. You could see if the Decorator pattern would be enough if your refinements/additions don't go too deep.

Comment: After some more practice with refinements I can now understand what you're doing in this answer. Specifically with `obj.extend(StringPatch)`, I at first tried `obj.instance { "".foo }` to test it but I now realize that wouldn't work because of lexical scope. All in all, thanks - this pattern of dual-purpose patches, I've incorporated it into my core extensions gems such as [gemmy](http://github.com/maxpleaner/gemmy)

Answer (score 2):

I appreciate the other answers but I think I have to add my own.

It seems there's very little leeway with `using` - the error that it can't be used in methods is serious. The best wiggle room I found is to iteratively call it, passing a variable as argument.

So if I have two patch classes, I can make a constant `Patches`, a list that includes both. Then in the class/module I want to load the patches, I can run the iterative `using`.

```
module StringPatch
  refine String do
    def patch; :string_patch; end
  end
end

module HashPatch
  refine Hash do
    def patch; :hash_patch; end
  end
end

Patches = [StringPatch, HashPatch]
class C
  Patches.each { |x| using x }
  def self.test
    [''.patch, {}.patch]
    new.test
  end
  def test
    [''.patch, {}.patch]
  end
end

C.test
```

The `using` does make the patches available in both instance and class scope.

The limitation is that there is no way to abstract away the `using` call.

I can't say `Patches.each &method(:using)`

or move `Patches.each { |x| using x }` to a method,

or use `eval "Patches.each { |x| using x}"`